# ¿Búsqueda en un ArrayList usando Treemap?

Tags: java, estructuras-de-datos, árboles

Quería saber (ya que es la primera vez que uso TreeMap y estuve investigando) si esto es posible de hacer ya que tengo una clase llamada "Sistema" en la cual existe una variable:

```
private Doctor objD; //LA CLASE DOCTOR CONTIENE UN ARRAYLIST DE LAS CONSULTAS    
Treemap<int, String> arbol = new Treemap<>();
```

Lo que quiero hacer es buscar con mediante el treemap todas las consultas que fueron hechas a ese doctor usando como parámetro el nombre del doctor, la firma del método sería la siguiente:

```
ArrayList<Consulta> listarConsultasDoctor(String doctor)
```

La clase Doctor contiene:

```
private String nombreDoctor;
private ArrayList<Consulta> listaConsultas;
```

Perdón por no dar mucho detalle es que es lo único que tengo hasta ahora de código y por más que busco no sé como seguirlo.

He llegado a esto pero sigo sin entender mucho.

//Esta es la clase Doctor.

```
private ArrayList<Consulta> lstConsultas=new ArrayList<Consulta>();
    private TreeMap<String,Consulta> arbolConsultas = new TreeMap<String,Consulta>();
    private String nombre;  

      public ArrayList<Consulta> listarConsultasDoctor(String nombreDoctor)
        {
            ArrayList<Consulta> consultasDoctor = new ArrayList<>();
            for(int i = 0; i < lstConsultas.size(); i++ )
            {
                int key = lstConsultas.indexOf(i);
                if(getNombre().equals(nombreDoctor))
                {
                    if(arbolConsultas.get(key).equals(nombreDoctor))
                    {
                        consultasDoctor.add((Consulta) arbolConsultas.values());                    
                    }
                }                   
            }
            return consultasDoctor;     
        }
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: No sería mas simple solo hacer un HashMap?, "HashMap<Doctor, ArrayList<Consulta>> algo = new HashMap<>();"

Comment: @Javadoub Sí, pero tengo que hacerlo con algo de orden logarítmico, por eso.

Comment: ¿Dónde están los árboles?

Comment: @sstan ¿en qué clase? si a eso te referís está en la clase "Doctor"

Answer (score 2):

Con la información que proporciona:

```
Treemap<int, String> arbol = new Treemap<>();
```

la definición del Treemap arbol es incorrecta, recuerde que los parámetros para el tipo de objeto no pueden ser primitivos, por lo que no puede declararlo de tipo int, además el nombre de la clase es TreeMap y no Treemap, por lo tanto la declaración correcta es

```
TreeMap<Integer, String> arbol = new TreeMap<>();
```

Ahora bien, de acuerdo a su pregunta intuyo que lo que desea es crear un TreeMap donde la llave sea un String representando el nombre del objeto de tipo Doctor y el valor asociado a esa llave es un ArrayList con objetos de tipo Consulta. Si eso es lo que se desea la declaración correcta del TreeMap es

```
TreeMap<String, ArrayList<Consulta>> arbol = new TreeMap<>();
```

Al hacer lo anterior está declarando un objeto de TreeMap llamado arbol que almacenará pares (String, ArrayList<>). Con esa estructura puede implementar el método listarConsultasDoctor para que use el parámetro que recibe y busque en el TreeMap el ArrayList de Consulta asociado a ese objeto, si es que existe. Ya de usted dependerá instanciar el objeto de tipo Doctor con el nombre y el ArrayList devuelto por ese método.

Como comentario adicional no encuento mucho beneficio en crear la variable arbol de tipo TreeMap, con un HashMap es suficiente para el propósito que persigue.

Comment: Hola, primero que nada muchas gracias por responder, sí, es cierto que con HashMap sería suficiente pero como contesté a un comentario anterior preciso hacerlo con una estructura logarítmica en este caso, a lo que he llegado fue a esto que sigue sin funcionarme. (Lo pongo en la pregunta porque acá no me da el espacio.)

Comment: 1. ¿Por qué la solución que le propuse no funciona? 
2. ¿A qué se refiere con 'estructura logarítmica'? ¿a que la complejidad de la búsqueda de los objetos tenga complejidad computacional O(logn)?

Comment: Sí, exactamente, tiene que ser orden(logn) además de que seguramente no me funciona por mis pésimas habilidades para programar y mi poco conocimiento.

Comment: Entonces su pregunta original está mal formulada, porque el enunciado no menciona de forma explícita eso y ese dato es importante para responderle. 

Por otro lado, de acuerdo con la documentación de Java, se garantiza que la búsqueda e inserción de datos en un TreeMap tenga complejidad O(logn). https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html

Comment: Es bastante probable si que esté mal formulada, gracias por la respuesta.